# Send variable along within include block

Tags: html, css, django

I'm working on a personal Django project where my plan is to make some sort of function in my site in form of a CSS Marquee (scrolling text).

I was able to make a marquee.html file with the code from [here](http://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/css-scrolling-text.cfm), and use it on several pages on my site using {% include "marquee.html" %} blocks, but the displayed string in the marquee is within the HTML file itself (marquee.html) between `<p>`-tags

Is there any way to send a variable/string along with a `{%include "" %}` block that replaces/adds to the `<p>` tags at the end of the marquee code?

(e.g. `{% include "marquee.html" {{ stringToDisplay }} %}` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current context is available for the included template. You can use the "with" option to send any additional context.

```
{% include "marquee.html" with message="Hello" %}
```

and in your marquee.html template

```
<div>{{ message }}</div>
```

The `include` documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

Comment: Damn, that looks so simple... Thanks! It works right of the bat.
I've added the reference link to my favorites for future reference :)